# Using domDocument, and parsing info, I would like to get the 'href' contents of an 'a' tag

Tags: php, domdocument

This displays the what is between the `a` tag, but I would like a way to get the `href` contents as well.

Is there a way to do that using the domDocument?

```
$html = file_get_contents($uri);
$html = utf8_decode($html);

/*** a new dom object ***/
$dom = new domDocument;

/*** load the html into the object ***/
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

/*** discard white space ***/
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

/*** the table by its tag name ***/
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

/*** get all rows from the table ***/
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

/*** loop over the table rows ***/
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $a = $row->getElementsByTagName('a');
    /*** echo the values ***/
    echo $a->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br />';
    echo '<hr />';
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mere inches away from the answer -- you've already extracted the `<a>` tags inside your foreach loop.  You're grabbing all of them in a [DOMNodeList](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), so each item in that list will be an instance of [DOMElement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php), which has a method called [getAttribute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php).

`$a->item(0)->getAttribute('href')` will contain the string value of the href attribute.  Tada!

---

It's possible that you might get an empty node list.  You can work around this by checking that the first item in the list is an element.

```
$href = null;
$first_anchor_tag = $a->item(0);
if($first_anchor_tag instanceof DOMElement)
    $href = $first_anchor_tag->getAttribute('href');
```

Comment: I believe you mean `getAttributeNode('href')`?

Comment: No, I mean I'm confused and didn't actually read the docs (that I took ever so very long to find) for `getAttribute` and blindly assumed it did the wrong thing (as is always the case with the DOM) and it returned a node instead of the actual value of the node. Oops!  This has been fixed.

Comment: Ah, `getAttribute('href')` returns a string, which means you don't need the `->nodeValue`. Better, anyway.

Comment: When I use this I get the following error: `Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object`

Comment: It's quite possible that the DOMNodeList that you got back was empty.  I'll edit my post with how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $a->getAttributeNode('href')->nodeValue."<br />";
```