# How to get main image from url in php? (Like Facebook post)

Tags: php, url

I try to get many more site to get this solution but all sites give me direct image file but i want as below.

if some URL has some feature image or a post image i want to get and display preview on something URL.

**ex. i set** http://google.com

**i want this**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Open Graph Protocol of a webpage by php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454644/how-to-get-open-graph-protocol-of-a-webpage-by-php)

Comment: sorry guys but i don't undertand this

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ that is the same question i refer...

Comment: ok you both are right. lovely solution!