# Using Rich Preview meta tags as images html css

Tags: html, css, meta-tags

When you send a link via text, facebook message, or any mainstream messaging client you'll notice it generates a "rich preview". This is basically an image that pops up of the website you are linking.

I understand how to set this property, for example

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="European Travel Destinations">
<meta property="og:description" content="Offering tour packages for individuals or groups.">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://euro-travel-example.com/thumbnail.jpg">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://euro-travel-example.com/index.htm">
```

but I want to know how to use it.

What I'm trying to do is setup a website with a table of links and I want each link to not be just a text link, but a square image. I want those images to be generated based on the links as rich previews just like in messaging clients.

(If it helps I'm trying to pull from google photos albums, so I'm hoping the rich preview will be the album cover and the title will be the name of the album)

Ex: I want to obtain, album title, and cover image from
https://photos.app.goo.gl/5VogRQ6CvoVOJKpq1

I would also like to use the title and description but I'm sure the process is the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454644/how-to-get-open-graph-protocol-of-a-webpage-by-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big companies like Facebook and Twitter all have their own spiders that periodically crawl the web looking at the DOM of websites. If they see the relevant tags, they'll generate their respective 'preview' automatically.

Literally all you need to do is have the right `<meta>` tags in your head section. You've demonstrated the **[OpenGraph](http://ogp.me/)** protocol in your sample above, which is used by most sites.

The basic tags, according to OpenGraph are:

> `og:title` - The title of your object as it should appear within the graph, e.g., "The Rock".
>
> `og:type` - The type of your object, e.g., "video.movie". Depending on the type you specify, other properties may also be required.
>
> `og:image` - An image URL which should represent your object within the graph.
>
> `og:url` - The canonical URL of your object that will be used as its permanent ID in the graph, e.g., `http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/`.

There's a number of others, though those are the main ones that you need.

Sites often define their own prefixes though. Twitter, for example, additionally uses a custom `twitter:` prefix to allow for **[some extended functionality](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/guides/getting-started)**.

Facebook has a **[debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)** through which you can submit your URL to have them forcibly update their preview, and Twitter has their own **[card validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator)** which will also forcibly crawl the site.

Simply wait for the site in question to crawl your own website, or submit your site manually through a respective tool, and your preview will be crafted. This preview will apply to **anyone** who attempts to hotlink to your website, not just you as the person who used the tool.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I do understand that, I'm not trying to set my own tags, I'm trying to obtain the data from the google photos website to use

Comment: Like for example I want to do this <img src="*google.com image meta tag*" height="42" width="42">

Comment: In that case I have *no idea* what you're trying to do. You'd just reference the image in an `<img />` tag; there's no metadata associated with an `<img />` tag.  You would just use something like `<img src="https://images.google.com/images/image1.jpg">`.

Comment: I know how to set an image, what I want is my website to automatically generate the image based on the url I give it. Exactly like the message clients do. That way I don't manually have to set every image myself.