# What tags are bots interpreting when creating a preview of the main picture

Tags: html, twitter, telegram

Wondering which tags e.g. Twitter/Telegram/*-bots are using to recognize, that at a given link, there is a main image they want to show inside their preview.

Comment: Do you mean the HTML meta tags which says to the Telegram/Twitter that what is image to show as the main preview image? Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48758954/using-rich-preview-meta-tags-as-images-html-css answer your question?

Comment: @AliKhalili I think I do ;)  --- Thanks I will check that