# regex - replace spaces IN stored element

Tags: php, regex

I have a HTML page in a string, and I need to replace all the spaces in the a href references with %20 so my parser understands it.

So for example:

```
<a href="file with spaces.mp3">file with spaces.mp3</a>
```

needs to turn into

```
<a href="file%20with%20spaces.mp3">file with spaces.mp3</a>
```

One space works fine since I can just use

```
(.+?)([ *])(.+?)
```

and then substitute it with %20 in between $1 and $3

But how would you do it for multiple and an unknown number of spaces, while still having the file name to put the %20's in between?

Comment: want to replace all spaces or only ones in href... what about src for example?

Comment: Here we go again: [Don't parse (X)HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066) And you probably want a proper URL encoder.

Comment: It's just to replace spaces, I don't see how it would kill my HTML

Comment: [DOMDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278418/using-domdocument-and-parsing-info-i-would-like-to-get-the-href-contents-of) then run `str_replace()`.

Comment: Also @Dexa, I only need the references in <a href>, it has to do with my parser that I'm writing. The src (for img tags) already works without replacing the spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not recommended to use regex, here's a potential regex that works for your example:

```
(?:<a href="|\G)\S*\K (?=[^">]*")
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/uZ8sC0)

```
(?:
  <a href="   # Match <a href=" literally
|
\G            # Or start the match from the previous end-match
)
\S*           # Match any non-space characters
\K            # Reset the match so only the following matches are replaced
 (?=[^">]*")  # Ensure that the matching part is still within the href link
```

The above regex could also break on certain edge-cases, so I recommend using DOMDocument in like Amal's excellent answer which is more robust.

Comment: Your result works most of the time, but for some matches it just doesn't seem to work. I can't find the problem...
http://regex101.com/r/zE2zA1

Comment: @Axon That's because a character class doesn't keep the order of characters. Using a negative lookahead would work better here: [link](http://regex101.com/r/jB3aM8).

Comment: Dayumn, that's one complex regex. But it seems to work fine, thanks for your help man.

Comment: @Axon Sorry about the complexity ^^; It took me a while to be able to understand such regexes too, so it's natural to feel that way. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 4):

HTML is not a regular language and cannot be properly parsed using a regular expression. Use a DOM parser instead. Here's a solution using PHP's built-in DOMDocument class:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $tag) {
    $href = $tag->getAttribute('href');
    $href = str_replace(' ', '%20', $href);
    $tag->setAttribute('href', $href);
}

$html = $dom->saveHTML();
```

It basically iterates over all the links and changes the `href` attribute using [`str_replace`](http://php.net/rawurlencode).

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/127697)

Comment: Only works for some examples: `echo rawurlencode('http://example.com/file with spaces.mp3');` Use `str_replace()` or maybe pull out the basename and encode that.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: Ah. You're right. I've updated the answer to use `str_replace()` instead.

Comment: This is probably the best result, the only problem is that I have to work with HTML encoded strings, so &lt; and &quot; for < and " and such, so the DOMDocument can't read these in.

Comment: @Axon: Simply replace `$dom->loadHTML($html);` with `$dom->loadHTML(htmlspecialchars_decode($html));`.